How Do I Rig the Eyes and Tongue Properly So They Can Move?
I'm doing a Blender tutorial on rigging and am having trouble with rigging the eyebrows and the tongue. For some reason the eyebrows move strangely as part of the eyebrow moves but the rest stay still and the tongue's controllers aren't where the tongue is and so I cannot move the tongue like the way it is in the video. I tried weight painting them but nothing changes. If anybody could find out a solution I appreciate it. Thanks.
This is the tutorial I'm working on:
https://youtu.be/IOjH0eG43Ak?list=PLok698dKQ_Hj10eKx73qPJRktkB1r8SN5




hello please show a screenshot and share your file

I added two screenshots. You can see the controller in light blue for the tongue was moved, but doesn't make any changes to the tongue itself.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

make sure that the tongue is assigned to the vertex group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control it?

Currently the tongue is assigned to vertex group "Tongue". I also have vertex groups "ORG-Tongue" and "DEF-Tongue".  Is Tongue.001, 002 etc. the bones that control the tongue?

Please share your file (remove the useless parts): https://blend-exchange.com/

What parts should be removed? Should I just keep the head?
